# Processed as Activity: Cron job output

Tags: cron, cron-job

Recently we have had our cron email us anytime there is an output as typically that only occurs when there is an email. `Processed as Activity: Cron job output` - I have the same cron running on other installations and I do not get this output - is this normal?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the inbound email processor configured? It has that as output. And it sounds like you are sending cron logs to the email processor.